# Rails jQuery truncate with 'read more & read less' link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to find a way to have comments displayed with a "read more" link that will not refresh the page when clicked.  The below code will not refresh the page but if any individual link is clicked all comments will be expanded instead of just the one comment.  I'm looking for a good way to have comments truncated and then display just a single comment when the "read more" link is clicked without a page refresh.

```
  <% @post.comments.order(created_at: :desc).each do |comment| %>
    <b><%= comment.user.first_name.capitalize + " "%><%= comment.user.last_name.capitalize %></b>

    <% if comment.content.length > 100 %>
      <div class='textControl'><%= truncate(comment.content, length: 100) %></div>
      <div class='textControl' style='display:none;'><%= comment.content %></div>
      <%= link_to '...Read more', '', class: "read-more-#{comment.id} textControl" %>

      <script>
        $('.read-more-<%= comment.id %>').on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $('.textControl').toggle();
        })
      </script>
    <% else %>
      <%= comment.content %>
    <% end %>

    [<%= link_to ' Edit', edit_group_post_comment_path(comment.post.group, comment.post, comment) %> |
    <%= link_to 'Delete ', group_post_comment_path(@group, @post, comment), 
                           method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this comment?' } %>]
    <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.updated_at) %>                                   
    <br><br>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look you can do this without extra hidden classes like you can remove this, actually, you don't need to use these extra lines

```
<div class='textControl' style='display:none;'><%= comment.content %></div>
<%= link_to '...Read more', '', class: "read-more-#{comment.id} textControl" %>
```

and the actual line will look like this

```
<div class='textControl'><%= comment.content %></div>
```

because you are truncating the jquery, also you don't need this condition

```
<% if comment.content.length > 100 %>
```

because if comment content less then 100 then it doesn't show `Read more` link

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Configure/customize these variables.
    var showChar = 100;  // How many characters are shown by default
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "Read more";
    var lesstext = "Read less";
    

    $('.textControl').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();
 
        if(content.length > showChar) {
 
            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
 
            var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';
 
            $(this).html(html);
        }
    });
 
    $(".morelink").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
a.morelink {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}
.morecontent span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Greater then 100</h3>
<hr>
<p class="textControl">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>

<h3>Less then 100</h3>
<hr>
<p class="textControl">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

Comment: If there is a `\n` in content, it won't be displayed. You may add `white-space: pre-wrap;` in `textControl` style to handle this case.